# scrape oddsportal for nfl money lines

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe, web-scraping

I've been working on this for a couple weeks and I think I'm close but could use some help. I've been trying to scrape oddsportal to pull the games and money lines

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/american-football/usa/nfl- 2017-2018/results/")
games = browser.find_element_by_class_name('table-main').text
```

This returns a string with all the rows of the table separated by '\n10' and all the table entries separated by '\n'

```
 "American Football\n»\n USA\n»\nNFL 2018/2019\n03 Feb 2019 - Play Offs 1 2 B's\n22:30 Los Angeles Rams - New England Patriots 3:13\n+110\n-127\n10\n27 Jan 2019 - All Stars 1 2 B's\n19:00 NFC - AFC 7:26\n-106\n-118\n10\n20 Jan 2019 - Play Offs 1 2 B's\n22:40 Kansas City Chiefs - New England Patriots 31:37 OT\n-172\n+148\n10\n19:05 New Orleans Saints - Los Angeles Rams 23:26 OT\n-164\n+140\n10\n13 Jan 2019 - Play Offs 1 2 B's\n20:40 New Orleans Saints - Philadelphia Eagles 20:14\n-385\n+312\n10\n17:05 New England Patriots - Los Angeles Chargers 41:28\n-196\n+166\n10\n00:15 Los Angeles Rams - Dallas Cowboys 30:22\n-345\n+281\n10\n12 Jan 2019 - Play Offs 1 2 B's\n20:35 Kansas City Chiefs - Indianapolis Colts 31:13\n-208\n+175\n10\n06 Jan 2019 - Play Offs 1 2 B's\n20:40 Chicago Bears - Philadelphia Eagles 15:16\n-286\n+231\n10\n17:05 Baltimore Ravens - Los Angeles Chargers 17:23\n-149\n+129\n10\n00:15 Dallas Cowboys - Seattle Seahawks 24:22\n-149\n+129\n10\n05 Jan 2019 - Play Offs 1 2 B's\n20:35 Houston Texans - Indianapolis Colts 7:21\n-127\n+108\n10\n31 Dec 2018 1 2 B's\n00:20 Tennessee Titans - Indianapolis Colts 17:33\n+194\n-233\n10
```

if i run the following I get closer but I still can't figure out how to get to the ultimate goal of having a dataframe with 4 columns: game date, teams, money line 1, money line 2

```
game_list1 = re.split('\n10', table_main)
```

returns:

```
["American Football\n»\n USA\n»\nNFL 2017/2018\n04 Feb 2018 - Play Offs 1 2 B's\n22:30 New England Patriots - Philadelphia Eagles 33:41\n-196\n+173",
 "\n28 Jan 2018 - All Stars 1 2 B's\n19:00 AFC - NFC 24:23\n+124\n-147",
 "\n21 Jan 2018 - Play Offs 1 2 B's\n22:40 Philadelphia Eagles - Minnesota Vikings 38:7\n+129\n-147",
 '\n19:05 New England Patriots - Jacksonville Jaguars 24:20\n-333\n+279',
 "\n14 Jan 2018 - Play Offs 1 2 B's\n20:40 Minnesota Vikings - New Orleans Saints 29:24\n-233\n+197",
 '\n17:05 Pittsburgh Steelers - Jacksonville Jaguars 42:45\n-303\n+254',
 '\n00:15 New England Patriots - Tennessee Titans 35:14\n-909\n+608',
```

so I think I'm getting closer but I can't figure out where to go from here as looking for patterns changes due to different numbers of games on different dates

dataframe would look like this except it wouldn't have score:

```
    date         game                money_line1   money_line2
0   04 Feb 2018  Patriots - Eagles   -196          +173
```

before this I had been trying to loop through it, running this returns 1 row, as it looks like every unique element I am looking for has the class name odd.deactivate:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/american-football/usa/nfl-2018-2019/results/")
time.sleep(2)
tab_main = browser.find_element_by_class_name('odd.deactivate').text
tab_main

'22:30 Los Angeles Rams - New England Patriots 3:13\n+110\n-127\n10'
```

but trying to loop through it with elements and xpaths has not worked, here's my current attempt:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/american-football/usa/nfl-2018-2019/results/")
time.sleep(2)
tab_main = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('odd.deactivate')
game_list = []
for line in tab_main:
    game = line.find_element_by_xpath('/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]')
    ml1 = line.find_element_by_xpath('/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]')
    ml2 = line.find_element_by_xpath('/tbody/tr[4]/td[6]')
    game_row = (game, ml1, ml2)
    game_list.append(game_row)
```

this gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-646-e1f07f8ecd68> in <module>
      5 game_list = []
      6 for line in tab_main:
----> 7     game = line.find_element_by_xpath('/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]')
      8     ml1 = line.find_element_by_xpath('/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]')
      9     ml2 = line.find_element_by_xpath('/tbody/tr[4]/td[6]')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath)
    349             element = element.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')
    350         """
--> 351         return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
    352 
    353     def find_elements_by_xpath(self, xpath):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    657 
    658         return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENT,
--> 659                              {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
    660 
    661     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    631             params = {}
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 
    635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it has the `<table>` tags, I'd go with pandas' `.read_html()` function as it specifically parses table tags. The tricky part here is there are multiple headers as the data, followed by the data, so you just need to figure out how to iterate through those.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/american-football/usa/nfl-2017-2018/results/")

df= pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]

dateList = []
gameList = []
money_line1List = []
money_line2List = []

for row in df.itertuples():
    if not isinstance(row[1], str):
        continue
    elif ':' not in row[1]:
        date = row[1].split('-')[0]
        continue
    time = row[1]
    dateList.append(date)
    gameList.append(row[2])
    money_line1List.append(row[5])
    money_line2List.append(row[6])

result = pd.DataFrame({'date':dateList,
                       'game':gameList,
                       'money_line1':money_line1List,
                       'money_line2':money_line2List})
```

**Output:**

```
print (result.to_string())
            date                                         game  money_line1  money_line2
0   04 Feb 2018    New England Patriots - Philadelphia Eagles       -196.0        173.0
1   28 Jan 2018                                     AFC - NFC        124.0       -147.0
2   21 Jan 2018       Philadelphia Eagles - Minnesota Vikings        129.0       -147.0
3   21 Jan 2018   New England Patriots - Jacksonville Jaguars       -333.0        279.0
4   14 Jan 2018        Minnesota Vikings - New Orleans Saints       -233.0        197.0
5   14 Jan 2018    Pittsburgh Steelers - Jacksonville Jaguars       -303.0        254.0
6   14 Jan 2018       New England Patriots - Tennessee Titans       -909.0        608.0
7   13 Jan 2018         Philadelphia Eagles - Atlanta Falcons        120.0       -139.0
8   07 Jan 2018        New Orleans Saints - Carolina Panthers       -278.0        233.0
9   07 Jan 2018          Jacksonville Jaguars - Buffalo Bills       -417.0        333.0
10  07 Jan 2018            Los Angeles Rams - Atlanta Falcons       -256.0        217.0
11  06 Jan 2018         Kansas City Chiefs - Tennessee Titans       -417.0        341.0
12   31 Dec 2017          Atlanta Falcons - Carolina Panthers       -227.0        189.0
13   31 Dec 2017        Baltimore Ravens - Cincinnati Bengals       -417.0        325.0
14   31 Dec 2017          Denver Broncos - Kansas City Chiefs       -169.0        145.0
15   31 Dec 2017     Los Angeles Chargers - Las Vegas Raiders       -312.0        259.0
16   31 Dec 2017       Los Angeles Rams - San Francisco 49ers        218.0       -263.0
17   31 Dec 2017               Miami Dolphins - Buffalo Bills        118.0       -139.0
18   31 Dec 2017         Seattle Seahawks - Arizona Cardinals       -385.0        307.0
19   31 Dec 2017    Tampa Bay Buccaneers - New Orleans Saints        225.0       -270.0
20   31 Dec 2017      Tennessee Titans - Jacksonville Jaguars       -139.0        119.0
21   31 Dec 2017            Detroit Lions - Green Bay Packers       -333.0        267.0
22   31 Dec 2017          Indianapolis Colts - Houston Texans       -244.0        202.0
23   31 Dec 2017            Minnesota Vikings - Chicago Bears       -909.0        604.0
24   31 Dec 2017         New England Patriots - New York Jets      -1429.0        861.0
25   31 Dec 2017        New York Giants - Washington Redskins        191.0       -227.0
26   31 Dec 2017         Philadelphia Eagles - Dallas Cowboys        165.0       -192.0
27   31 Dec 2017       Pittsburgh Steelers - Cleveland Browns       -227.0        190.0
28   26 Dec 2017      Philadelphia Eagles - Las Vegas Raiders       -476.0        374.0
29   25 Dec 2017         Houston Texans - Pittsburgh Steelers        328.0       -417.0
30   24 Dec 2017          Arizona Cardinals - New York Giants       -172.0        150.0
31   24 Dec 2017            Dallas Cowboys - Seattle Seahawks       -213.0        177.0
32   24 Dec 2017   San Francisco 49ers - Jacksonville Jaguars        181.0       -213.0
33   24 Dec 2017     Carolina Panthers - Tampa Bay Buccaneers       -476.0        384.0
34   24 Dec 2017             Chicago Bears - Cleveland Browns       -244.0        202.0
35   24 Dec 2017           Cincinnati Bengals - Detroit Lions        150.0       -172.0
36   24 Dec 2017          Kansas City Chiefs - Miami Dolphins       -556.0        436.0
37   24 Dec 2017         New England Patriots - Buffalo Bills       -556.0        437.0
38   24 Dec 2017         New Orleans Saints - Atlanta Falcons       -233.0        198.0
39   24 Dec 2017         New York Jets - Los Angeles Chargers        264.0       -323.0
40   24 Dec 2017          Tennessee Titans - Los Angeles Rams        206.0       -244.0
41   24 Dec 2017         Washington Redskins - Denver Broncos       -164.0        143.0
42   24 Dec 2017        Green Bay Packers - Minnesota Vikings        347.0       -435.0
43   23 Dec 2017        Baltimore Ravens - Indianapolis Colts       -909.0        644.0
44   19 Dec 2017       Tampa Bay Buccaneers - Atlanta Falcons        270.0       -333.0
45   18 Dec 2017           Las Vegas Raiders - Dallas Cowboys        129.0       -149.0
46   17 Dec 2017   Pittsburgh Steelers - New England Patriots        114.0       -133.0
47   17 Dec 2017       San Francisco 49ers - Tennessee Titans       -133.0        114.0
48   17 Dec 2017          Seattle Seahawks - Los Angeles Rams       -108.0       -108.0
49   17 Dec 2017        New York Giants - Philadelphia Eagles        274.0       -333.0
```

Comment: that's awesome, thank you!!! Now I guess my next step would be to loop through the pages to get a whole season instead of running page by page. New to selenium. thank you for the help!

Comment: Did you find a way to loop through pages?